# Using the Object Attribute Output node to drive the Orthographic Scale of the camera

Tags: animation-nodes, orthographic

I´m trying to animate the orthographic scale of the camera with Animation Nodes so that I can procedually change the value and don`t have to rely on keyframing it. Using the Object Attribute Output node I managed to change values of different modifiers but when i try to use it on the camera object, it gives me the error "Attribute not found".
[image]I'm not sure if this is the right way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data.ortho_scale` as attribute.